# Difference between "Optional<ButtonType>.get()" and "alert.getResult()"

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I was fiddling around with JavaFX and got to a webpage which lists all the different types of dialog boxes and the creator of the content used something like this:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog");
alert.setHeaderText("Look, a Confirmation Dialog");
alert.setContentText("Are you ok with this?");

Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
    // ... user chose OK
} else {
    // ... user chose CANCEL or closed the dialog
}
```

And what I did was the following:

```
alert.showAndWait();
if (alert.getResult() == ButtonType.OK)
{
    //User chose OK
} 

else
{
    //User chose other
}
```

I read the documentation of most of these methods and classes and what I can gather from this is that he uses `Optional` in case the method `showAndWait()` returns a `null`. According to the docs the `showAndWait()` method returns an `Optional.ofNullable` which may or may not be `null`. And then in the if statement he gets the result from that `Optional<ButtonType>` which contains whatever `showAndWait()` returned and compares it.

In my part of the code I went straight to get the result from the `Alert` instance with `getResult()` and compared it which might be bad because `showAndWait()` might return null.

Is that the main difference? Protection against null? Or is there another reason as to why using Optional might be better other than that? Just wondering if someone could explain this better.

extra: Also I'd be very grateful if someone could tell me what the return type of `showAndWait()` means, it returns : `Optional<R>`. I'm assuming it's a generic type, but I've never seen that before, I've only seen `E` `T` `N` etc.

Thank you for any input on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is that the main difference?**

No. See the comment below from the javadoc of [Dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html)

> Shown below is three code snippets, showing three equally valid ways
>   of showing a dialog:
>   *Option 1: The 'traditional' approach*
>
> ```
>  Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
>  if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
>      formatSystem();
>  }
> ```
>
> *Option 2: The traditional + Optional approach*
>
> ```
>  dialog.showAndWait().ifPresent(response -> {
>      if (response == ButtonType.OK) {
>          formatSystem();
>      }
>  });
> ```
>
> *Option 3: The fully lambda approach*
>
> ```
>  dialog.showAndWait()
>       .filter(response -> response == ButtonType.OK)
>       .ifPresent(response -> formatSystem());
> ```
>
> There is no better or worse option of the three listed above, so
>   developers are encouraged to work to their own style preferences. The
>   purpose of showing the above is to help introduce developers to the
>   Optional API, which is new in Java 8 and may be foreign to many
>   developers.

**Protection against null?**

Protection exists in all options either with `isPresent()` or with `ifPresent()`.

**Or is there another reason as to why using Optional might be better other than that?**

No reason. [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) was introduced with Java 8—the guys at Oracle want the developers to get familiar with it soon. Although the same feature was already introduced to "Java World" with 3rd-party APIs, now it is part of the JDK itself. You may read its advantages etc. on online blogs, for example [Tired of Null Pointer Exceptions?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html).

**Also I'd be very grateful if someone could tell me what the return type of showAndWait() means, it returns : `Optional<R>`.**

`R` is a  *type parameter* (or type variable) with "R" standing for "**R**esult". It can be anything (`X`, `RE`, `Rezult` etc.) that does not clash with reserved Java keywords or class names in your classpath; generally it is a single uppercase letter by convention:

[Java Tutorials > Generics > Generic Types:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

> ### Type Parameter Naming Conventions
>
> By convention, type parameter names are single, uppercase letters. This stands in sharp contrast to the variable [naming](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) conventions that you already know about, and with good reason: Without this convention, it would be difficult to tell the difference between a type variable and an ordinary class or interface name.
>
> The most commonly used type parameter names are:
>
> - E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
> - K - Key
> - N - Number
> - T - Type
> - V - Value
> - S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types
>
> You'll see these names used throughout the Java SE API and the rest of this lesson.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer.